# How to initialize a generic property with child class of generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, initialization

I want to fill a generic property with one of the child classes. But I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Child1' to 'T'

How can I do it?

For example:

Consider these parent and child classes:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public int P1 { get; set; }

    public abstract int DoSomething();
}
public class Child1 : Parent
{
    public override int DoSomething() { return P1 * 2; }
}
public class Child2 : Parent
{
    public override int DoSomething() { return P1 * 3; }
}
```

And also consider this sample generic class:

```
public class Sample<T> where T: Parent
{
    T ChildObject { get; set; }

    public int Test()
    {
        ChildObject = new Child1 { P1 = 2 }; // Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Child1' to 'T'

        return ChildObject.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

---

**More explanation:**

My mistake was I was trying to **initialize child class in the generic class**. Following the accepted answer, I should just add **new constraint** and do `ChildObject = new T { P1 = 2 };` and then use `ChildObject.DoSomething();`.

---

**Solution:**

```
public class Sample<T> where T: Parent, new()
{
    T ChildObject { get; set; }

    public int Test()
    {
        ChildObject = new T { P1 = 2 }; // Fixed :)

        return ChildObject.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `where T : parent, new()` and `ChildObject = new T();`?

Comment: new Child1() as T, but if T is Child2, then the ChildObject becomes null

Comment: @vc-74 +1 You pointed the solution so fast. Really amazing **new constraint**. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `Sample` class to:

```
public class Sample<T> where T : Parent, new()
{
    T ChildObject { set; get; }
    public Sample()
    {
        ChildObject = new T(); 
    }
}
```

you can now create an instance as:

```
var sample = new Sample<Child2>();
```

In order for this to work, `Child1` and `Child2` need to have a public parameterless constructor. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: It means that **I can use parent methods and properties in Sample class** with this way. but if I want to **use child methods and properties**, I should use it **out of Sample class**. `ChildObject.ParentMethod();` vs `sample.ChildObject.ChildMethod();` Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more illustrative example:

```
class Tiger : Mammal {}
class Zebra : Mammal {}

public class Sample<TAnimal> where TAnimal: Mammal
{
    TAnimal ChildObject { set; get; }
    void Test()
    {
        ChildObject = new Tiger(); // Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Tiger' to 'TAnimal'
    }
}
```

Let's say we used `Zebra` for `TAnimal`. It will give us:

```
public class Sample<Zebra> where Zebra: Mammal
{
    Zebra ChildObject { set; get; }
    void Test()
    {
        ChildObject = new Tiger(); // Bang!
    }
}
```

Both `Zebra` and `Tiger` are mammals but it doesn't mean that Zebra *is* Tiger hence the error.